# Problem with downloading F4 IDE (Mac IOS)

Tags: ios, eclipse, macos, project, fantom

I am working on a project based on the Fantom language.
But I can't download it because of the "metadata/.log." problem.

[image]

I understand that I have to delete this file
The problem is that I don't find in the folder where I saved the project
When I open the "f4workspace" it's empty but when I click on "see more information" of the folder I see that it contains an element:

[image]

can anyone help me??

I downloaded F4 from the link below:
http://www.xored.com/products/f4/f4-downloads/

Comment: That .log file contains details of the error that is occuring - you need to read it and show us what it says. Because the .log file name starts with '.' Finder will not normally show it - use Cmd + Shift + .  to get Finder to show hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

The `.log` file starts with a dot so it'll be automatically hidden by MacOS (and linux) - see articles like [How to Show Hidden Files on Mac](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/show-hidden-files-mac-3520878/) to view them.

Do note that F4 currently requires Java8 to work and will not work on any later versions of Java.

Also, should the installation finally work for you, there's a slightly updated version of [F4 available on GitHub](https://github.com/xored/f4/releases).

Comment: thanks for your answer!
BuI still haven't found the .log file in the library...

By the way, Do you know in which platform I can work to learn Fantom language expect from F4 on Mac iOS ?

Comment: @QuestionMac22 see [IDEs on fantom-lang.org](https://fantom-lang.org/ide) for a list of F4 alternatives.